# JUnit5 Spock 2, @ExtendWith does not work

Tags: testing, spock, junit5

i am trying to set up testing platform for our new project.
We want to use Spock 2 with JUnit 5.

And now i want to use `@ExtendWith` annotation in Spock based test.

Here is an example:

```groovy
@SpringBootTest(classes = ExtensionTest.class)
@ExtendWith(ClassExtension.class)
class ExtensionTest extends Specification {
    void "test"() {
        when:
        true

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()
    }
}
```

Given Extension (`ClassExtension`) is implementing interfaces: `BeforeAllCallback` and `AfterAllCallback`.

```java
class ClassExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {
    @Override
    void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
       ...
    }

    @Override
    void afterAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
       ...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Extension is not being run.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Spock 2.x does not use the Jupiter Engine but implements its own [`SpockEngine`](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/runtime/SpockEngine.java) and its own [`SpockExecutionContext`](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/runtime/SpockExecutionContext.java) based on the Jupiter API. Obviously it does not support Jupiter extensions, probably because Spock has its own extension mechanisms for annotation-driven and global extensions.

Bottom line: I recommend to port your JUnit Jupiter extension to a Spock extension. There you also have better means to hook into the Spock lifecycle.

Comment: Thank You very much... So it will not work...
I really wanted to use JUnit extensions because it is availbale to get Spring Context in that extension by calling ```SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(extensionContext)```
I wanted to use it before class execution to prepare context for E2E tests.
I know that spock has its own extensions but it is not possible to get SpringContext inside them

Comment: I am not a Spring user, so I have no experience with it, but is the [Spock Spring module](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M2/all_in_one.html#_spring_module) inadequate for you?

Comment: Yes it is and i am familiar with it.
Maybe my question wasn't clear enough: 
I want to use Spring Context before and after tst suite. Spock has methods like ```setupSpec``` but it does not allow to use spring cotnext inside it. That is why i started to search for something different.

Answer (score 2):

The thread is old, but in case anyone would be searching for the similar problem, there is a way now to use Junit 5 extensions with Spock 2: [spock-junit5](https://github.com/xvik/spock-junit5).

I did not try it with spring boot extension, but it should work because all required jupiter extension interfaces supported by the library.

Comment: It works. I use spock-junit5 to integrate already written jupiter-api extension in spock specs. At least @RegisterExtension fits my tasks

Comment: it works with @RegisterExtension but not when used with spring DataJpaTest

Comment: I tried and DataJpaTest works in this simple case: https://github.com/xvik/spock-junit5/issues/74#issuecomment-1921193015 (note that spock-spring is not required)